# Symbolic link creation pointing Firefox

Tags: firefox, java

I am getting this error on Firefox when trying to confirm a file over the internet:

```
Error type: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
Error message: Native Library /usr/lib/firefox/libmozsqlite3.so already loaded in another classloader
```

I've been told to create a new symbolic link for this path to solve this problem, but I don't know how to do it, could you please help me out on this one?

Comment: I am getting this error too when I try to digitally sign my taxes declaration. I have been doing this for the last six years using Ubuntu without any problem so far.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install oracle java 7, set it as default and restart Firefox:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default
```

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html